# Getting confused with complex Haskell typeclass declarations

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have a type alias for a monad transformer stack:

```
type KStat s a = ReaderT (KStatRoot s) (ExceptT KindError (ST s)) a
```

I need to abstract users away from this type, largely because the `KStatRoot` structure was causing cyclic dependencies.  I therefore created a separate module and defined a typeclass for it:

```
class (Monad (m s), MonadError KindError (m s)) =>
      MStat m s where
    liftToST :: ST s a -> m s a
    kstatNewRef :: a -> m s (STRef s a)
    kstatReadRef :: STRef s a -> m s a
    kstatWriteRef :: STRef s a -> a -> m s ()
```

This definition compiles OK (albeit needing `{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses,FlexibleContexts #-}` to work, but I can see why both of those are required), and I've been able to convert some use sites to the typeclass and have them type check, so everything seems OK there.  But I'm struggling to work out how to define my instance for the class:

```
instance MStat (KStat s a) s where
    liftToST = lift . lift
    kstatNewRef = liftToST . newSTRef
    kstatReadRef = liftToST . readSTRef
    kstatWriteRef r v = liftToST $ writeSTRef r v
```

gives me the error:

```
src/KindLang/Data/KStat.hs:27:17:
    The first argument of ‘MStat’ should have kind ‘* -> * -> *’,
      but ‘KStat s a’ has kind ‘*’
    In the instance declaration for ‘MStat (KStat s a) s’
```

which kind of makes sense, but then if I change `KStat s a` to `KStat` in the instance header I get this error:

```
src/KindLang/Data/KStat.hs:27:10:
    Type synonym ‘KStat’ should have 2 arguments, but has been given none
    In the instance declaration for ‘MStat KStat s’
```

which seems to basically saying the exact opposite.

I'm using these language extensions in the module I declare the instance:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses  #-}
```

How do I resolve these errors?

Complete file demonstrating the errors follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleContexts,
  FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses  #-}

import Control.Monad.Except
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Data.STRef

data KStatRoot s = KStatRoot
data KindError

class (Monad (m s), MonadError KindError (m s)) =>
      MStat m s where
    liftToST :: ST s a -> m s a
    kstatNewRef :: a -> m s (STRef s a)
    kstatReadRef :: STRef s a -> m s a
    kstatWriteRef :: STRef s a -> a -> m s ()

type KStat s a = ReaderT (KStatRoot s) (ExceptT KindError (ST s)) a

instance MStat (KStat s m) s where
    liftToST = lift . lift
    kstatNewRef = liftToST . newSTRef
    kstatReadRef = liftToST . readSTRef
    kstatWriteRef r v = liftToST $ writeSTRef r v
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete example with imports?

Comment: @ErikR - the complete files involved are rather large, but if Iyou can give me some clue what you're trying to achieve maybe I can work something out?

Comment: Just give a minimal example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @ErikR - OK, added a module with everything in the same place that gives the same errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first error is "correct" (you need to use a type of two arguments in the instance declaration), and your attempted fix makes sense.

However, a `type` synonym doesn't really exist without its arguments. That is, after

```
type Foo a = ...
```

you can't use `Foo` by itself. `Foo` has to be applied to an argument in order to be processed by the type checker. This is the cause of your second error.

The only workaround I see is changing `KStat` to a `newtype`:

```
newtype KStat s a = KStat{ runKStat :: ReaderT (KStatRoot s) (ExceptT KindError (ST s)) a }
```

That will let you use `KStat` without arguments. You'll just have to add explicit `runKStat`/`KStat` conversions everywhere.

Comment: I was starting to think this was the solution.  Looking for other peoples' code that did the same thing was showing me that just about everyone used `newtype` rather than `type` for any non-trivial monad type... fortunately I'm already using functions to abstract running the monad, so it should be a nice easy change. :)